# MQ in command prompt

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed MQ in my machine(have checked that with regedit32) But i get the error "cannot recognise the command" when i type "runmqsc" in command prompt (Environment variable is set for mqjms.jar ) What am i missing ? I want to create quemanagers and queue through command prompt in window

Answer (score 3):

What version of MQ are you using? (You can check by entering `dspmqver` in the command prompt)

To create a queue manager you should use the command `crtmqm`. For eaxmple if you'd like to create a queue manager using the default values and name it MyQueueManager, you should enter the following command:

```
crtmqm MyQueueManager
```

In any case I would recommend on creating queue managers through MQ Explorer, supposing you've installed it. It's much easier and fool proof.

If you still want to work with the command prompt, after you've created your queue manager, type the following:

```
runmqsc MyQueueManager
```

This command will open the MQSC shell which you can use to create objects (such as queues) in your queue manager.

To create a queue with default values named 'MyQueue' enter:

```
DEFINE QLOCAL('MyQueue')
```

Comment: Thanks.. But the commands were not executed.they were not recognised. Looks like the installation was not done correctly because in an another machine where MQ is installed i was able to create queue managers and queues thorugh command as well as Explorer . Also, I dint have explorer installed in my machine not sure if there is a seperate download for it or comes with the MQ server installation

Answer (score 2):

You look like a beginner to MQ. I suggest you read on MQ first little bit and then start exploring. You can find information on MQ v7.5 here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.pro.doc/q001010_.htm?cp=SSFKSJ_7.5.0%2F1.

BTW there is no 'runmqm' command. You can use 'dspmqver' command to display the version of MQ you have installed and 'dspmq' to display list of queue managers running on that machine.

Comment: Yea. Beginner, and that was a mistake i meant runmqsc Thanks for the share

Answer (score 2):

For installation on Windows, it is always recommended to reboot the server before beginning in order to save the registry and mitigate the effects of ill-behaved programs with memory leaks and such.

Then after installing MQ and the latest Fix Pack, reboot again.  This saves the registry again and also picks up the new environment variables.

Finally, at this point run the setmqinst command.  This sets up the defaults that point to the correct directory for that installation.  If your bin directory is unrecognized and Windows can't find the executables, I suspect this is the part you have missed.